# I having Gridview in modal with pagination ,when I select Activity by checkbox click and I close modal only selected page checkbox unchecked not all

Tags: javascript, c#

I having Gridview in modal with pagination in c# ,when I select Activity by checkbox click and I close modal only selected page checkboxs unchecked not all.

I having Gridview in modal with pagination in c# ,when I select Activity by checkbox click and I close modal only selected page checkboxs unchecked not all.

$('#MainContent_ActivitySelectionDiv table tr td input:checkbox').each(function () {
$(this).prop('checked', false);
});